# Use lottie in slick carousel slide

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js, lottie

I want to use lottie animation in slick carousel but after render page, lottie animation not display (outside slick slide work fine).

My code:

```html
 <div class="slick-carousel">
  <div class="tip">
    <div class="animation">
       <lottie-player ...></lottie-player>
    </div>

  <div class="tip">
    <div class="animation">
       <lottie-player ...></lottie-player>
  </div>
</div>
```

In browser `div.animation` is render without `lottie` inside

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, Lottie player does work on display: none which is added by slickjs css for each slide, but I have resolved this with the below code. No "src" on lottie-player this prevents Lottie from playing on load, and I used the data-src attribute to get the JSON path and initialized Lottie player on slickjs "init" callback. I have used setTimeout function because slickjs "init" callback does not trigger immediately when slickjs is initialized on page load.

```
<lottie-player class="lottie-player" data-src="/path/to/json/" background="transparent" speed="1" direction="1" mode="normal" loop autoplay></lottie-player>
```

```
var $el = jQuery(".hero-slider-content");
        $el.on("init", function (event, slick, direction) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery("lottie-player").each(function () {
                    var players = jQuery(this).attr("data-src");
                    this.load(players);
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
        $el.slick({
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false,
            dots: true,
            autoplay: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        });
```